# $Variable is not expanding in Library definition in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

This Groovy Jenkinsfile script works

```
@Library('jenkins-library@master')_

pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-host-01' }
    stages {
    ...
    ...
```

But it don't work if I change the first line to use a variable `$MY_BRANCH`

```
@Library('jenkins-library@$MY_BRANCH')_
```

Got below error:

```
ERROR: Could not resolve $MY_BRANCH
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git rev-parse $MY_BRANCH^{commit}" returned status code 128:
stdout: $MY_BRANCH^{commit}
```

`MY_BRANCH` is a parameter to the job, so this variable is available, but its not getting expanded in Jeenkinsfile script, is there a different syntax to use?

My pipeline job is setup like below, the above code is in `Jenkinsfile`.

[image: job parameter]

[image: pipeline config]

Comment: Try to use double quotation marks in library statement: `@Library("jenkins-library@$MY_BRANCH")`. Groovy doesn't interpolate single-quoted strings.

Comment: @zett42 Tried that already, didn't help.

Comment: Try `library "jenkins-library@$MY_BRANCH"`. If it still doesn't work try `node { library "jenkins-library@$MY_BRANCH" }`. See [Loading Libraries Dynamically](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)